# How to use MPE for MPI c++ project?

Tags: c++, mpi, mpic++

MPE is very useful for visualizing MPI programs, but it only provides compiler wrappers for C and Fortran: `mpecc` and `mpef77`, respectively. How can I use it if my MPI project is written in C++ and is normally compiled with `mpic++`, not `mpicc` (and so it can't be compiled with `mpecc`)?

How do I setup (1) the MPE library itself and (2) my C++ project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple, nonetheless I struggled with it for days.

Steps shown below works with MPICH 3.3.2 on Linux (Ubuntu 18) run with WSL2 - some adjustments may be necessary in different evnironments.

---

### MPE library setup for c++

You setup the MPE library normally, the same way you would for a C project - the necessary steps are:

1. Download and extract the latest MPE archive (I've used [MPE 2-1.4.9](ftp://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/mpi/mpe/mpe2.tar.gz) from [here](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/perfvis/download/index.htm#MPE))
2. Navigate to extracted directory:

   `cd mpe2-2.4.9b`
3. Configure library's build process - in my case the following command worked:

   `./configure MPI_CC=mpicc MPI_F77=mpif77 prefix=$HOME/installs/mpe2 MPI_CFLAGS=-pthread MPI_FFLAGS=-pthread`

   Explanation:

   - MPE is written in C, so we use **mpicc** to compile it - we do not (yet) specify how to build our project, so we do not use mpic++. If we use `mpic++` as `MPI_CC`, the MPE library won't compile.
   - specifying Fortran flags isn't strictly necessary, but this way we avoid unneccessary errors in compilation output
   - *prefix* (installation path) is an arbitrary path of your choice, just remember what you have inserted here as it will be necessary in further steps
   - I had to provide manual linkage of the `pthread` library - this may/may not be neccessary depending on your system
4. Compile the MPE library:

   `make`
5. Install the compiled library:

   `make install`

---

### Using MPE in c++ project

Since we cannot use a predefined compiler wrapper `mpecc` to compile c++, we have to link the necessary libraries manually, as we would do with any other library.

Suppose we have a file `main.cpp` with following content:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <mpe.h>

/* other necessary includes */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPE_Init_log();

    /* some MPI and MPE stuff */

    MPE_Finish_log("test");
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The specific command which allows to build a c++ file with MPI and MPE calls is:

`mpic++ main.cpp -o main -I/$HOME/installs/mpe2/include -L/$HOME/installs/mpe2/lib -lmpe -pthread`

Explanation:

- We use `mpic++` to link the all MPI items automatically
- `$HOME/installs/mpe2` is an arbitrary installation path you've specified when configuring the MPE library
- `-I` flag tells the compiler where to look for header files (the ones we `#include`)
- `-L` flag tells the compiler where to find the compiled library items (implementation of functions defined in included header files)
- `-l` flag tells compiler to actually link our executable with specific library (which can be found thanks to us specyfing search location with `-L` flag)
- I had to link `pthread` manually for MPE to work, but that may depend on your system

If you use **cmake** for building your project, the following CMakeLists.txt should work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)  # not necessarily 3.5, it;s just my setup

project(mpi_test)  # arbitrary project name

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER mpic++)

include_directories($ENV{HOME}/installs/mpe2/include)  # again, it's the MPE installation path
link_directories($ENV{HOME}/installs/mpe2/lib)  # again, it's the MPE installation path

add_executable(main_exp src/main_exp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main_exp mpe pthread)  # again, pthread may/may not be neccessary
```